# How do I expand my map plotting code to plot altitude with the latitude/longitude aswell?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code that plots latitude and longitude on a map with python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#gets data
df = pd.read_csv('LOGGER96.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
df.columns = ["sats", "latitude", "longitude", "altitude", "temperature", "pressure", "time"]
mapimg = plt.imread('map.png')

#removes the zeros from the array to define the boundary
arrayLong = [i for i in df.longitude.tolist() if i != 0]
arrayLat = [i for i in df.latitude.tolist() if i != 0]
BBox = ((round(min(arrayLong),8),   df.longitude.max(),      
         round(min(arrayLat),8), df.latitude.max()))
print(BBox)

#plots the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,7))
ax.scatter(df.longitude, df.latitude, zorder=1, alpha= 0.4, c='hotpink', s=10)
ax.set_xlim(BBox[0],BBox[1])
ax.set_ylim(BBox[2],BBox[3])

ax.imshow(mapimg, zorder=0, extent = BBox, aspect= 'equal')
```

This is how a plot would look:

[image]

Now notice how there is also an altitude list of data, with the same dimensions, I want to use that to plot it into a 3d plot, but using pyplot3d it just gives me `"NotImplementedError: It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect on 3D axes"`.

How would I go about programming a threedimensional altitude, longitude and latitude map? (with the nice picture of the map as a floor)

Late edit: The original code is based on this web article: https://towardsdatascience.com/easy-steps-to-plot-geographic-data-on-a-map-python-11217859a2db.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have a similar need :)

Comment: No, I eventually made an empty 3D plot that has latitude and longitude on XY (In hindsight I could have converted this to relative distance in the same unit as altitude) and altitude on Z and a small 2D map (like shown in the post) plot with colors for the dots (using matplotlibs 'colormap') to represent different altitudes.